# In a Firebase Cloud Function, is it possible to retrieve the result of admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a Firebase Cloud Function, is it possible to retrieve the result of `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` without directly inserting the request into a call to `set()` or `update()`?

When i write a document to a collection, i can set a current server timestamp as one of the values like this without issue:

```
admin.firestore().collection(`/entries`).doc().set(
 foo:bar,
 date: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
);
```

However, i need to write the same data to a section in my Realtime Database once the write to Firestore has completed.

Is it possible to get the result of `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` prior to writing to the database?

I have tried setting it into a constant like this but it did not work:

```
const postDate = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Before anyone responds, i am well aware that i can retrieve a timestamp for the Realtime database using `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` however, that is not what i am trying to do. I need access to the resulting date that gets written to my Firestore document as noted above.

If this is not possible, is there any harm in refactoring to just use javascript in my cloud function to get a UTC date as a *current* date? If all of my data is written using this same method to write dates to the databases, what is the harm? Or are there issues with generating consistent dates in a cloud function?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get the server timestamp using Firestore without first writing it to a field.  The value of `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is a sentinel token that only has meaning when interpreted by Firestore as a field value.

You might be able to try to *guess* its value after having written one first, if you are willing to make assumptions about the round trip latency between your client and Firestore, but that's probably not going to work the way you want.

Comment: Right, understood. What about using UTC javascript dates in a cloud function? I updated my question to ask about this as an alternate. I am aware that this is a non starter client side for all the obvious reasons, but what about in a cloud function?

Comment: Or better yet, maybe I should rely on a cloud function that simply listens for writes to my collection, retrieve the resulting date at that point, and then subsequently write it to my Realtime database. Im sure there will be latency, but at least date will match.